# How windows manages to send messages with more than two parameters?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, event-handling, message, sendmessage

Studying about message-handling in MFC, I've found that:

*A message comes with 2 parameters that give you more information about the event. Each parameter is a 32-bit value: lParam and wParam.*

So when I created a user-defined message wwith no parameters, I sent it with the code:

```
pParentOfClass ->SendMessage(WM_RECTANGLECHANGED,0,0);
```

but just to be curious, how windows manages to send messages with more than two parameter like `WM_SIZE`.

Comment: Parameters can be packed into the `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` of `LPARAM` or `WPARAM`. See [MSDN for WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx) for example.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already quickly stated in the comment by Roger Rowland, multiple parameters are often packed into the low and/or high order of the LPARAM and WPARAM parameters when using messages.

What you probably mean by more parameters than two, is the fact that MFC has it's own event handler wrappers which already took the necessary information from the LPARAM and WPARAM parameters and forwarded it to it's own event handler implementations, which of course can have as many parameters as desired.

**Example with WM_SIZE:**

Originally, the WM_SIZE message is sent with LPARAM containing some flags and WPARAM containing width and height (through packing into low and high order).

Now MFC receives that message, gets all info it thinks is necessary for the user and calls its own event handler:

```
afx_msg void OnSize( 
   UINT nType, 
   int cx, 
   int cy  
);
```

That's basically it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h464d4f3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MAKEWPARAM (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632664(v=vs.85).aspx) and MAKELPARAM.